# Custom STS SSO with redirection to another web site in a different domain

Tags: single-sign-on

All,

I am working on a SSO Project using WIF for my current employer .Registered users can log in to a portal that is public facing and receive access to a suite of applications . My employer has purchased a COTS Application(Claims Aware) hosted  in another city . What they would like to do is the following

1a)Have Registered users log into the Portal located  at  portal.domain1.com
1b)During the login process , the portal communicates with an STS in the background which returns a signed and encrypted token back to the browser
2)User sees a link to the COTS Product on the Portal Page and clicks on it
3)They are redirected to  app.domain2.com 
4)App.domain2.com does not need to autenticate the user again since they receive the identity token from the portal .The user is able to establish a session from his browser with app.domain2.com 
5)The browser is able to persist the token across all requests to the domain2 server

We will not be doing ADFS 2.0 but a Custom STS . My question is  , is there a way to do it in  SAML ?

Thanks,

Raja

Answer (score 0):

You can push SAML authentication statements.

When the link is clicked on portal.domain1.com you use javascript to post a saml statement to app.domain2.com.

Comment: Thanks Tom. Can you send me a sample of how to issue  SAML authentication statements from  .NET 4.5/WIF ?

Comment: Afraid not, I'm a java bod and that was my last job :)